# How can I create multiple images in an array in java using a for statement?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, image, slick2d

I wish to link to the 52 card images to an array, but without adding them individually. I was thinking something like creating an array and using a piece of code something like this.

```
Image[] card;
card = new int[52];
for (int c = 1; c<=52;c++)
{
    card[c] = 
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, but the cards in the file are labelled 1-52 so I figured that would be an easier way(and a better way to impress my teacher) to create the card values. I thnk I might also have to change the ranks system and use that as well. I'm using slick2d for the graphics.

How can I use that piece of code(or a different piece of code) to assign the images to a variable?

Comment: Indices start at 0, not 1

Comment: Provide format of the imput file exactly.

Comment: cart is an array of Images, so create it as `card = new Image[52];`.

Comment: i made it 1 and equal to 52 so my computer science teacher will grade me better because he can get confused if he sees a 51 and a 52 next to each other (he's not the brightest). thanks dystroy i will try to work from that

Comment: @HaydenHolligan `card[c]` will fail with `c==52`. That's why you must start at 0 and test c<52.

Comment: or you could also do "card[c-1] = "

Comment: don't you think that `Image[]` should not be initialized with `int[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out slick2d javadoc at http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/ and find the Image class you are trying to use.

Try this code

```
Image[] card = new Image[52];
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        card[i] = new Image(/*insert constructors here*/);
    }
```

If you read the documentation you will find out there are many different ways to create a new image object. e.g. I downloaded an ace of spades image and the following code should create an array of 52 aces of spades

```
Image[] card = new Image[52];
String fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\con25m\\Pictures\\ace_spades.jpg";
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        card[i] = new Image(fileLocation);
    }
```

You can either find out if slick2d has images for all of the cards in a standard 52 deck or download images of each card yourself, come up with a naming convention for the images and then update the fileLocation string in the forloop. e.g.

```
Image[] card = new Image[52];
String fileLocation = new String();
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\con25m\\Pictures\\" + i + ".jpg";
        card[i] = new Image(fileLocation);
    }
```

Note: instead of using the number 52 all of the time consider using a final variable and using that variable instead. e.g.

```
final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;
Image[] card = new Image[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++)...
```